# How to Re-render Child-Component for New Updated Props Value

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to update the **Progress** and **Steps** components from **Ant-Design UI** with new props value as shown below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Progress, Steps } from 'antd'

const Step = Steps.Step

const Parent = ({ a }) => {

  const haveCompleted = () => {
    var intr = setInterval(() => {
      if(c < 754) {
        console.log(c)
        return c++
      }else {
        clearInterval(intr)
      }
    }, 300)
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragement>
      <div>
        <Steps> />
          <Step description={a !== null ? haveCompleted() : null} ... />
          <Step ... />
        </Steps>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Progress percent={haveCompleted()/754*100 || 0} ... />
      </div>
    </React.Fragement>
  )
}

export default Parent;
```

On logging to browser console the value gets updated in function but doesn't get reflected in components.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In React you need to modify the `state` so it re-renders the DOM otherwise it will look the same.

Comment: Right. So you're saying if I change the parent to class component, add state called "c", change the return statement to that of setState and finally use state as direct props value for child components?

Comment: But then to prevent infinite rendering loop wheel to initialize the haveCompleted function?

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the state anywhere. You are just executing an inline function. The state should be passed down to the component and re-render the affected child or your component should hold state. As you can see from the `Ant` documentation there should be a `current` prop on `Steps` which you have not included. Finally the `description` prop is of type `string` | `ReactNode` and your function is returning neither.

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake in returning incorrect prop type value in 'description'. No, I'm not using 'current' as I'm using 'status' prop in Step. But other than that, is using 'setInterval' okay, and by the way, then where to initialize hasCompleted function as its changing the state?

Answer (score 0):

Worth-noticing mistake as pointed out by helpful folks above:

- Not using `state` to render the component

**Solution:**

- Changing parent component to Class-based
- Adding `State` called `c`
- Calling `haveCompleted` function inside `ComponentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to update `State`
- Passing state `c` directly to child component